# Safari hijacked by Safe Finder. Change homepage preference greyed out

Tags: macbook-pro, safari, virus

I must've downloaded this virus when I was prompted to download Flash thinking it was the real software. Now whenever I open Safari I get linked to this search engine. I had this issue with Chrome opening up TapuFind and a few other search engines - I fixed this by completely reinstalling Chrome.

I've tried many methods to remove it but can't get it to un-grey out:

1. Tried changing in the preferences panel but it's greyed out.

   [image]
2. I don't have "Profiles" in my System Preferences.

   [image]
3. I tried using Malwarebytes but it didn't help.
4. I tried a safe start with Safari (opening the app while holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd>) but that didn't allow me to edit the preferences panel.
5. Tried booting into Safe mode, but again that didn't help to let me edit the homepage.
6. Tried cleaning the Cache entirely but again, didn't help (as well at that list thing).
7. I don't think I have a modified hosts file

   [image]

Is there anything else I can do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried safe starting Safari? Hold SHIFT while launching and it will disable all extensions.

Comment: Hi, yes, I've tried this but it hasn't helped :(

Answer (score 2):

Deleting your Preferences properties file should do it.

1. Close Safari completely.
2. Open a Finder window and go to your Home folder (the one with your Username).
3. Go to the View menu, and select "Show View Options". (Alternatively, you can hit Command+J.)
4. At the very bottom of the options window, select (check the box) "Show Library Folder".
5. Now browse through these folders:
   Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Preferences
6. Once you drill down to Preferences, you'll see a file named com.apple.Safari.plist.  That's your preferences file.  Delete it.
7. Re-open Safari. Your preferences should all now be back to default.  You'll have to set things back the way you had them before, but you'll be rid of the messed-up settings.

That should do it!

Comment: I just tried this, but again, my homepage is still greyed out. Thank you though

Comment: Create a new Admin user on your Mac and login to that. If Safari is *still* messed up I'd be tempted to beck up only your vital data and reformat and start over. If it is OK then migrate your data to the new profile and delete the old one.

Answer (score -1):

Use MalwareBytes, (https://malwarebytes.com) a free anti-malware tool.  See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8591130 for more information and instructions.

There are multiple pages trying to get you to download other "removal" tools of questionable origin. (e.g. "Combo Cleaner")  MalwareBytes is widely known and respected

Answer (score -1):

Removing profiles is what worked for me.  Check out this [article](https://www.macworld.com/article/3353516/how-to-fix-a-grayed-out-safari-home-page-preference.html) for how to do it!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide **supporting info** as to why they're the best.  Answers should be self-contained so explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better/more complete than the others already provided.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer.